# how to know ruby bit in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I am in the need to install Oracle Instant Client Packages on ubuntu OS from [this link](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-instant-client.md#Donwload_Instant_Client_Packages).

Then I found there was note as-
***Note: use 32-bit packages for 32-bit ruby even though the OS is 64-bit.***

How to know running **ruby bit size ( 64 / 32bits)** in ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching a lot I came to see [this blog](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/177435)

So this is the way to know Ruby version-

1. Open terminal (Alt+t).
2. Type irb (to get entered in Ruby env.)
3. Type `['sanjay'].pack('p').size`as below-

---

```
2.3.1 :012 >   ['sanjay'].pack('p').size
 => 8 
2.3.1 :013 >
```

**you will get O/P 8 on 64bit, 4 on 32bit.**

Hope it will work for you too...